# jquery and javascript's closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am having the code below and javascript's closure together with anonymous functions are giving me a headache.

```
for (var i = 0, len = sites.length ; i < len ; i++)
{
  $("#thumb"+i).click(function() { $("#shader").show(); $("#thumbInfo"+i).show(); alert("#thumbInfo"+i); });
  $("#thumbInfo"+i+" .xbutton").click(function() { $("#shader").hide(); $("#thumbInfo"+i).hide(); });
}
```

Due to closure, i is always 5 (the sites array has 5 elements), so all the click handlers refer to the same id.

Any workaround?

Comment: IF you unroll the loop (replace it five times with `i` hardcoded) does it work? I have a feeling `i` is not the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always loop with jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
$.each(sites, function(i) {
  $("#thumb"+i).click(function() { $("#shader").show(); $("#thumbInfo"+i).show(); alert("#thumbInfo"+i); });
  $("#thumbInfo"+i+" .xbutton").click(function() { $("#shader").hide(); $("#thumbInfo"+i).hide(); });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use a closure in your for iteration:

```
for (var i = 0, len = sites.length ; i < len ; i++)
{
    (function(i) {
        $("#thumb"+i).click(function() {
            $("#shader").show(); 
            $("#thumbInfo"+i).show(); 
            alert("#thumbInfo"+i); 
        });
        $("#thumbInfo"+i+" .xbutton").click(function() { 
            $("#shader").hide(); 
            $("#thumbInfo"+i).hide(); 
        });
    }(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place a function returning a function and parameterized by `i` outside the loop. JSLint will encourage you to do this anyway, and some might find it more readable to boot.

```
function make_fn1(i) {
    return function() { $("#shader").show(); $("#thumbInfo"+i).show(); };
}
function make_fn2(i) {
    return function() { $("#shader").hide(); $("#thumbInfo"+i).hide(); };
}
for (var i = 0; i < sites.length ; i++)
{
    $("#thumb"+i).click(make_fn1(i));
    $("#thumbInfo"+i+" .xbutton").click(make_fn2(i));
}
```

However, this could be cleaned up in other ways. For starters, as long as you're using jQuery, `$("#shader, #thumbInfo"+i).show();` is more concise. Furthermore, in the current code the notion that the two functions either hide or show the same two elements is not factored out, so could be

```
function make_fn (i,showhide) {
    return function() { $("#shader, #thumbInfo"+i)[showhide]() };
}
for (var i = 0; i < sites.length ; i++)
{
    $("#thumb"+i).click(make_fn(i,'show'));
    $("#thumbInfo"+i+" .xbutton").click(make_fn(i,'hide'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var len = sites.length ;
for (var i = 0; i < len ; i++)
    {
      $("#thumb"+i).click(function() { $("#shader").show(); $("#thumbInfo"+i).show(); alert("#thumbInfo"+i); });
      $("#thumbInfo"+i+" .xbutton").click(function() { $("#shader").hide(); $("#thumbInfo"+i).hide(); });
    }
```

you might have been assigning 5 to i;

Comment: No, the closure gives access to the parent's variable `i`, which by the time the `click()` event is called, has beens set to `5`.

Comment: I can certify that this answer is incorrect. I will leave it here for reference.