# jQuery 'change' event inside loop not working

Tags: jquery, css, forms, bind

How is it that the first event bind works for all the submit buttons, yet the second applys the css only for the last one, regardless of what form it is listening to?

```
for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    var divI = "ind-" + i;
    var formID = document.forms["form-" + i];

    $(formID).bind("submit", validate);
    $(formID).bind("change", function(){
        $('#' + divI).css("background-color","green");
    });
}
```

Comment: @Marcus Was it really necessary to edit this? You've revived a question from 8 years ago.

Comment: Necessary?  No.  Value added?  Yes.  I had a slightly hard time reading the code so I just cleaned up the whitespace a bit.  Have I caused you grief somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It closure. Check this one
[jquery and javascript's closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846330/jquery-and-javascripts-closure)

Comment: Thanx @George Kastrinis, but what exactly is closure?

Comment: Closure is a combination of a function and some elements from its environment. [Closure on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) In your case, you have a function for 'change' but it uses divI which is not defined inside the function. It is defined in the function's environment.

Comment: OK thanx, I see from your link how to fix it, but why does it fail initially?

Comment: Check the last comment on the above link. "No, the closure gives access to the parent's variable i, which by the time the click() event is called, has beens set to 5"